# C# Keydown why the messagebox showed twice?

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("text");
            }
            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        }
```

I used this code, but the message box showed two times
Anyone who know how to solve this?
:D

Comment: Comment this `this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);` and try.

Comment: You should use the property box and let the ide declared this in designer... May be you have declared it in properties box and also in c# code twice. Just comment both lines and set values via designer properties and verify.

Comment: Yep, you should check like @Abhiverma said, if you have declared in properties box once, then you don't have to += handler again, or it will become twice when trigger.

Comment: The recommendations from @dr.null is valid. Because before using the +=, read it first. This notation is used in C# for the operator to specify an event handler method when you subscribe to an event. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/ for more detail.